# How to view and/or edit a .mdb Jet MS Access database file?

Tags: windows, file-format, database

I have a `.mdb` database file which originated from a MS Access Jet database.

Is the some way to view this database, and even better, a way to edit and export it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to install **mdbtools** and **mdbtools-gmdb** in order to get the mdb viewer for gnome.

[image]

I haven't used it myself, so i don't know if it's able to let you edit the database, but it gives you the option to export it, so maybe you can convert it to the oo-base version (odb).

I don't know why openoffice doesn't support it. I've read that is caused by MSDAO that cannot be installed in linux o/s, so only oo-base in windows can natively support it.

Anyway, you should give it a try i guess. I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks Pavlos.. mdbtools is currently read-only (according to [http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/] it will become writeable in the next version (but the current version seems to be from 2004, so I'm not waiting :)... As it stands now, it is functional for reading data via SQL and can export individual tables, and schemas. It doesn't seem to handle the standard MS UTF-16 unicode format, unless it can via a locale setting, but it is quite usable for looking at and exporting tables..  There might be more to it, as I've only looked a the GUI, and the CLI may do more, but it has its merits as it is.

Comment: glad to hear it helped ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LibreOffice Base with the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to manipulate Microsoft Access databases (.mdb and .accdb). For details, see the following answer

[Is it possible to open a Microsoft Access database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236)