# Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?

Tags: libreoffice, database, microsoft-office

I have a `.accdb` file created with Microsoft Office 2010 and I want to know if it is possible to open it with some native Ubuntu application like LibreOffice or OpenOffice, I know LibreOffice has `LibreOffice Base` but I can't figure out how to open or if it's even possible to open a `.accdb` file.

Is there any way I can open a `.accdb` file without Wine or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) it says it supports Access files but if we [look deeper](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Base/How_to_connect_to_a_Microsoft_Access_database) they have only tested in LibreOffice up to Office 2007.

Since you have an Office 2010 I would suggest trying out this [link](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_to_Microsoft_Access) since other users by the look of [this](http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg20678.html) have already tried.

Additionally the compatibility shown [here](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison:_LibreOffice_-_Microsoft_Office#Database_programme:_LibreOffice_Base_vs._Microsoft_Access) says how good LibreOffice Base is when relating to Microsoft Access 2010. At least up to version 3.6.

There is also a question on the Ask Libreoffice site about [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/4251/access-2010/) that mentions [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010/thread/33ad105c-b752-4f65-9913-32ea967171f4) where it is said that the 2007 format is different from the 2010 so it will not work correctly in LibreOffice 3.6 or below.

My only recommendation that does not include Wine or VirtualBox would be to use MS Office 2010 to save the Access file as a 2007 version (If possible) or a MDB format. At least while LibreOffice works on improving compatibility with 2010 in general.

Comment: I noticed this line [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison:_LibreOffice_-_Microsoft_Office#Database_program:_LibreOffice_Base_vs._Microsoft_Access): *'limited olders driver "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" works fine for read/write, while "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" driver only reads; ([fdo#43187](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43187)). **Driver only works on Windows**.'* - great...

Answer (score 65):

Yes, we can use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to connect to Access databases (.mdb and .accdb) in LibreOffice Base. Here's how I did it on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

***Important Note:***  These instructions apply to UCanAccess version 3.0.5 and later (including version 4.x). Before proceeding, verify that you are using the latest version of UCanAccess, available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/).

### One-Time Setup

First, I installed LibreOffice Base

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

Then I downloaded UCanAccess (`bin.zip` file) and unzipped it into the folder

```
~/Downloads/JDBC/UCanAccess
```

[image: HomeFolder.png]

**Note:** When unzipping the distribution file be sure to specify "Keep directory structure" (or similar, depending on your unzip tool) so the folder structure appears as in the screenshot above.

I launched LibreOffice (not Base, just LibreOffice itself)

[image: LibreOffice.png]

and chose Tools > Options

[image: ToolsOptions.png]

On the Advanced tab I clicked the "Class Path..." button

[image: ClassPathButton.png]

and then added the following JAR file using the "Add Archive..." button:

```
/home/gord/Downloads/JDBC/UCanAccess/loader/ucanload.jar
```

[image: ClassPathDialog.png]

Note that this is **ucanload.jar** in the **loader/** subfolder, not "ucanaccess-x.y.z.jar” in the UCanAccess home folder.

**Important:** You must close and re-open ***all*** LibreOffice (or OpenOffice.org) components for the new "Class Path...” value to take effect. That includes any "quick start” features or other related processes. (If you want to play it safe, simply restart your machine.)

### Per-Database Setup

I launched LibreOffice Base, and in Step 1 of the wizard I chose "Connect to an existing database (JDBC)"

[image: ExistingDatabase.png]

The Access file I wanted to manipulate was named "uca301demo.accdb" in my Documents folder, so in Step 2 the "Datasource URL" was …

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:///home/gord/Documents/uca301demo.accdb
```

*(note that Base supplies the `jdbc:` prefix for us, so all we need to enter is the remainder of the URL starting with `ucanaccess: …`)*

… and the "JDBC driver class" was

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver
```

[image: BaseJdbcPage.png]

In Step 3, I left the "User name" field empty and just clicked "Next >>".

In Step 4, I saved the LibreOffice Base database as "accdbTest.odb" in my Documents folder.

When the wizard completed it opened my LibreOffice database and I could see the tables and saved queries in the .accdb file

[image: BaseMainWindow.png]

### Troubleshooting

If you are using a distribution that installs LibreOffice Base by default (e.g., Linux Mint) then you may receive the error

> The connection to the data source "MyDatabase" could not be established.
>
> 'org.hsqldb.persist.HsqlProperties
> org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(java.lang.String, boolean, boolean)'

That is because LibreOffice has installed its own (rather old) copy of HSQLDB that conflicts with UCanAccess. To fix that, remove LibreOffice's copy of HSQLDB. For example, on Linux Mint that would be

```
sudo apt remove libhsqldb1.8.0-java
```

Also, if LibreOffice Base won't work for whatever reason you can use [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) instead. Installing the (free) Community Edition is as easy as

```
sudo snap install dbeaver-ce
```

Comment: Great work Gord. Any idea if this is using existing drivers? I'm having trouble getting this into my statistical software for importing Access Tables :)

Comment: Brilliant! But I needed to add jackcess-2.1.4.jar and hsqldb.jar to my java class path. (I did this by putting them in jdk/jre/lib/ext) Before that I kept getting an error message saying the driver was corrupt.

Comment: This is still working for LibreOffice 6.2! Thank you!

Comment: It does NOT work for me (Ubuntu Studio 20.10). I hangs on step 2, giving the error "The JDBC driver could not be loaded" (I'm trying to open an Access 2003 mdb file - created in Office 2010 for compatibility reasons). And no, Base won't open it even without this stupid "UCanAccess" thing.

Comment: @Phantômaxx - feel free to use something better than "this stupid 'UCanAccess' thing" if you can find one.

Comment: It seems there's no way to use the f***ing Libreoffice Base...

Comment: @Phantômaxx - I can't vouch for Ubuntu Studio 20.10 but I just tried the above instructions under Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and they worked fine for me.

Comment: There must be something wrong in Ubuntu Studio 20.10, then.

Comment: @Phantômaxx re: "There must be something wrong in Ubuntu Studio 20.10, then." — [Nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmF0p.png).

Comment: @GordThompson Of course there is, since **it does not work at all**.