# How do I get LibreOffice Base to access MS Access 2003 data

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

If I'm to leave Microsoft XP behind I need to work with my MS Access data files in Libreoffice Base or something similar.

How do I get LibreOffice Base to access MS Access 2003 data files?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install mdbtools from the ubuntu software center to be able to access Access files.

http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mdbtools

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get LibreOffice Base to access MS Access 2003 data files?

You can use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to allow LibreOffice Base to manipulate Microsoft Access database files. For detailed setup instructions see my answer to

[Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236)

Answer (score 0):

Simply open LibreOffice Base, and choose Open. Than change the filter to Any file (*.*) and choose your Accesss base file. However there may be some issues while importing bases.