# Opening an .accdb file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice, file-format, microsoft-office

I've received a Microsoft Access .accdb file (version 2010 I believe) that I need to get some data from.

How can I open it in Ubuntu? Is there any tool that would allow me to do so?

PS: Read-only is fine, if it has CSV exporting capabilities, the better.

Comment: Did you try `LibreOffice Database` to open it.

Comment: @SauravKumar: Yes, I even installed the additional ODBC plugins, but it doesn't to work with .accdb files.

Comment: I had a doubt.. Actually, I opened it very long time ago.. I don't remember what did I use.. Thought that it would be `OpenOffice Database`. Now cleared!!

Answer (score 11):

I just released an `access2csv` program written in Java based on Jackess. Code is [here](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access2csv), a binary is available [here](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access2csv/releases).

Answer (score 3):

**For Access 2000-2011**(both Read-Write)

[Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) is a pure Java library for reading from and writing to MS Access databases. It is part of the OpenHMS  project from Health Market Science, Inc. . It is not an application. There is no GUI. It's a library, intended for other developers to use to build Java applications.  It appears to be much newer than MDB tools, is more active and has write support.

Jackcess currently supports 2000-2010 files for read and writing but only reading for Access 97 files

**For Older 97 Access** (both Read-Write)

Try [MDB Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/)

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822378/how-to-open-an-accdb-file-in-ubuntu)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but both seem to be programming APIs, right? Having a GUI would be nice, or a simple CLI at least.

Comment: @AlixAxel Libre Office has support till access 2007 but doesmt support 2010.Easy solution would be saving as 07 and using libre office. btw check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-a-office-2010-access-files  and  http://askubuntu.com/questions/284359/can-microsoft-access-files-be-edit-in-ubuntu?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to connect to Access database files (.mdb and .accdb) from applications like LibreOffice Base. For detailed instructions on how to set it up, see my answer to

[Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236)

Answer (score 2):

To export all the tables on Linux to CSV format try this command:

```
mdb-tables -d ',' database.accdb| xargs -L1 -d',' -I{} bash -c 'mdb-export database.accdb "$1" >"$1".csv' -- {}
```

You can use `mdbtools` also into windows via WSL (Ubuntu on Windows or Debian on Windows):
Then install it in console with:

```
sudo apt install mdbtools
```

Comment: Error: Table does not exist in database

Answer (score 0):

I just had success with [mdb-tools v0.99](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools/releases/tag/v0.9.0) and this bash script

https://github.com/pavlov99/mdb-export-all

```
bash mdb-export-all.sh full-path-to-ms-access-db.accdb
```