# How do you open a .accdb file on Linux?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have tried to open a .accdb file on libreoffice and a few other ms access clones, but without any success. I saw some questions asked almost 10 years ago proposed installing something, but I am not sure if that is a safe or relevant option anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening an .accdb file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342925/opening-an-accdb-file-in-ubuntu) . Read ALL the answers. Some are from 2019-2020.

Comment: Access DBs are designed for Access Only, opening one without Office is **nearly impossible** because they keep changing things.  I would suggest you attempt some of those other solutions in the linked item from user535733 above, but ultimately you should probably just open this on Windows for MS Access, dump the tables, etc. as CSVs, and then use that data to populate an actual DB system with the data and links.  Access DBs are... well, MS Proprietary Data Format, so... :P