# Database for Ubuntu compatible with Microsoft Database?

Tags: compatibility

I am trying Ubuntu 12.04 booted from a DVD disk before I install it.  I currently have windows 8 (which I hate) and I have a couple of Data base programs with my movies, hundreds of movies, in them.   Is there a database available for Ubuntu that is compatible with Microsoft Database?  There are too much data in the current database file for me to have to rewrite the program.

So far, I love the Ubuntu 12.04.  I have been able to access my microsoft works spreadsheet files and documents with no problem.  And I like the thuderbird email and just about everything else about Ubuntu 12.04.  I just need to be able to access my database files and to write lables and envelopes.

Comment: When talking about "Microsoft Database", you mean "Microsoft Access"? Or a different piece of software? If it is MSAccess please edit your question in order to include your current version. If it is a different software please include the details. Thank you!

Comment: You mean Access with "microsoft database"?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you mean Microsoft Access as the database.

Easiest alternative to use on Ubuntu is LibreOffice Base. Your system probably already has LibreOffice, but you will probably have to add Base:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

Once installed, you should be able to open your Access file, but your mileage may vary, see here: [Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-a-office-2010-access-files)

Comment: I use Microsoft Works and it is the database that is included with the program.

Comment: Wow, seriously old software. I don't think there is anything on Ubuntu that will be able to open a Microsoft Works *.wdb file, but you may be able to convert it to a spreadsheet: http://www.codealchemists.com/worksdatabaseconverter/

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is a very widely used database system (not just on Ubuntu) (MariaDB is the open source clone of MySQL since MySQL got bought by Oracle).

Any database can export to and import from text files so all you need to do is create the database and the tables.

There is an explanation on how to get [data directly from Access to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html) on the mysql site so you can if you want to.