# Base 4.2.1 does not display Access Database Connection option

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

I am a relatively new user to Ubuntu. I would like to open Access database in Ubunutu to view the tables but cannot use Wine/MS Office. 
I have installed LibreOffice 4.2.1 alongwith base. Problem is that when trying to Connect to an Existing database, the option to use Access is not displayed.

Displayed options are
JDBC, Oracle JDBC, Thunderbird Address Book, Spreadsheet, dBASE, Text, MySQL, ODBC

Libre Office version 4.2.1, mdbtools is installed.

Regards,
Ali

Comment: * I have updated to latest base version and also to Ubuntu 14.04. Still cannot see option to view/open MDB databases. Tried uninstall and reinstall LibreOffice + mdbtools as well. But no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to connect directly to an Access database is only available in the Windows versions of LibreOffice Base. However, it is possible to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to give LibreOffice Base read/write access to a Microsoft Access database file (.mdb or .accdb).

For detailed instructions on how to set it up, see my answer to a similar question here:

[Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236)

Comment: Thanks. I never knew that the functionality to connect to Accdb is not supported on Linux version of LibreOffice.