# Is there an Ubuntu equivalent of Microsoft Access 2010?

Tags: windows

I have a relational database Access 2010 which I would like to run with an Ubuntu programme. Is this possible?

Comment: The equivalent will be [LibreOffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/), but I am not sure if this could work with Access Files.

Comment: According to https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/, it should work with MS Access.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-an-access-2010-database-file-without-using-wine-or-virtua - did that help?