# How to enable PDO-ODBC on Ubuntu + XAMPP in order to connect to MS-Access DB?

Tags: php, odbc

I want to use a mdb Access Database with PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18 + XAMPP. So I've installed the following packages, although not all of them may be required:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-odbc
sudo apt install libodbc1
sudo apt install unixodbc
sudo apt install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt install odbc-mdbtools
sudo apt install tdsodbc
```

After the installation odbc is still not listed as below shown:
    php -i | grep PDO

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

So the following entries are missing, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857):

```
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc
PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
```

I've restarted the machine and apache, nothing could help.

So, how can I enable PDO-ODBC on Ubuntu + XAMPP in order to connect to MS-Access DB?

I hope, someone can help.
Thanks in advance

Beste regards

Asg

Comment: This is older now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-an-access-2010-database-file-without-using-wine-or-virtua If MDB, is it an older Access database?

Comment: mdb or accdb, both are ok for me. I don't want to open the db in an application like office or so. I want to access the mdb or accdb via PHP (see link above).

Comment: Best not to use MS Access if at all possible. Or convert one time to any of the Linux compatible SQL databases.

Comment: It's not my choice. My customer wants MS Access, so I have to deal with it.
I'm still interested in help :( Thanks