# Having Problems loading JDBC driver on LibreOffice Base

Tags: libreoffice, database, microsoft-office

I'm trying to open a .mdb file by following the instructions from Gord Thompson in [Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-an-access-2010-database-file-without-using-wine-or-virtua/519571#519571) .

Though I do everything as described, I get "The JDBC driver could not be loaded".

What I find odd is, that after adding the Class Path "/home/markus/Downloads/JDBC/UCanAccess/loader/ucanload.jar", I can't see the new added class path listed anywhere. Shouldn't it be listed somewhere?

And yes, I restarted my system as was suggested.

Comment: After adding the jar file, it should be listed in the class path window (immediately after adding it, without a restart). Unless it's listed there, the "one-time setup" isn't finished. You may run LibreOffice from the command line to see if there are any errors visible on the console after trying to add the jar.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Regarding this point my formulation was not correct. What I meant is, that after adding the path, it is listed in the class path window but nowhere else.

Comment: Sorry, i can't reproduce this. I've tested with current UCanAccess (4.0.4) and LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 (just tested loading the UcanlaodDriver class, no db connection tested). You may nevertheless run LibreOffice from the command line. If the "Test Class" button throws an error, the Java stacktrace should appear on the console. You may add that stacktrace to your quersion, maybe it contains additional information.

Comment: Generally, there may be two possible causes for the error: (1) the jar isn't available when LO tries to access it - is it still there? (2) there's a typo in the db class name. But the name `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver` is still valid with 4.0.4. NB the class name is case sensitive, so it should be entered as written by Gord.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu! I appreciate your support. I finally was able to make it work. But I actually don't know how. What I did is, instead of restarting my system I just went on after adding the class path and then build the connection to the database in libreoffice base. Then I was able to to open the db in libreoffice base.